# Embed OLE Object in Wordpad

Tags: vbscript

IS there any way to embed an OLE object in the Wordpad application using some kind of scripting, say vb script.

Using native application we can do it through Insert->Object and then select any object that needs to be embedded. I need to do it through vbscript like we can do it in Excel/Word/Powerpoint.

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe that Wordpad can be auomated other than using the SendKeys workaound (not pretty). Is using Word instead an impossible option?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpad does expose an interface that can be instantiated using the ProgID "Wordpad.Document.1" as seen below.  However, it doesn't appear to have a type library associated with it (there's nothing to see in an object browser) and there is no documentation of any publicly accessible methods or properties.  It would seem to me that this was never intended to be used as a scriptable interface despite the fact that the following code will execute without error.

```
Set objWordpadDocument = CreateObject("Wordpad.Document.1")
```